# Why is Lamisil Once (terbinafine film-forming solution) marketed for athlete's foot, but not for jock itch or ringworm?

Tags: medications, fungal-infection, athletes-foot, jock-itch-tinea-cruris, ringworm

Lamisil Once (terbinafine film-forming solution) is an over-the-counter antifungal medication. It's sold only in certain countries, such as Britain and Australia. You apply it once. It starts working right away. Then you wait a few weeks for it to finish working.

The maker, Novartis, advertises it as a treatment for athlete's foot. But the company [writes](http://lamisil.com.au/product-oncefilm.html) that it "is only recommended for the treatment of athlete's foot (tinea between the toes)". For jock itch (tinea cruris) or ringworm (tinea corporis / tinea capitis / tinea manuum), Novartis recommends that you choose a different product (such as ordinary Lamisil cream) instead.

Why does Novartis recommend that sufferers of jock itch and ringworm choose a less-convenient product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you apply Lamisil Once, it forms a medicated film. If you're careful, the film can remain on your skin for [up to 72 hours](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17559730). This will help to make sure that the optimal amount of medication will make its way into your skin.

Novartis [advise](http://lamisil.com.au/product-oncefilm.html) their customers:  "It is recommended to apply Lamisil Once after a shower or bath, and then wait 24 hours before washing your feet again. Keep the affected area clean by washing it regularly after the first 24 hours. Dry the skin thoroughly, but **be careful not to rub the skin**." (Emphasis mine.)

On its website, Kiwi Drug elaborates: "After 24 hours, showering may resume, but the application site ... should be gently patted dry, not rubbed, as doing so will remove the film. ... With these considerations in mind it's easy to see how Lamisil Once may not be the best choice for treatment in some areas, such as the groin or armpits, that tend to ... rub against skin or clothing."

Based on all this, it seems to me that Lamisil Once might fail miserably if used for jock itch or ringworm. If you want to maximize your chances of success, it's probably wiser to choose a different product instead.